# Группировка объектов в массиве

Tags: javascript

Имеется, например, несколько объектов в массиве:

```js
let shop = [{
  id: 105,
  date: '2018-10-11',
  fact: 100,
  plan: 95
}, {
  id:105,
  date: '2018-10-12',
  fact: 105,
  plan: 100
}, {
  id:106,
  date: '2018-10-11',
  fact: 110,
  plan: 115
}, {
  id:106,
  date: '2018-10-12',
  fact: 120,
  plan: 115
}];
```

Нужно получить структуру из объектов с id и массивами факта и плана (выполнения продаж, например):

```js
let groups = [{
  id: 105,
  fact: [100, 105],
  plan : [95, 100]
}, {
  id: 106,
  fact: [110, 120],
  plan: [115, 115]
}];

console.log(groups);
```

Пытался использовать `reduce`, но тогда я складываю вообще все факты и планы, не учитывая id. Прогонял первый массив в `forEach` и `map`, но так же не могу понять, как мне оставить id уникальным, а `fact` и `plan` слить в массивы к этим id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Проходим по всем элементам `shops`
- Для каждого элемента ищем уже существующую группу по `id`
- Если группа найдена - добавляем в её списки `fact` и `plan` соответствующие значения элемента
- Иначе создаём новую группу со значениями из элемента и добавляем её в список групп

Реализации могут несколько отличаться, но суть такова:

```js
let shop = [{
  id: 105,
  fact: 100,
  plan: 95
}, {
  id: 105,
  fact: 105,
  plan: 100
}, {
  id: 106,
  fact: 110,
  plan: 115
}, {
  id: 106,
  fact: 120,
  plan: 115
}];

let groups = [];

for (let element of shop) {
  let existingGroups = groups.filter(group => group.id == element.id);
  if (existingGroups.length > 0) {
    existingGroups[0].fact.push(element.fact);
    existingGroups[0].plan.push(element.plan);
  }
  else {
    let newGroup = {
      id: element.id,
      fact: [element.fact],
      plan: [element.plan]
    };
    groups.push(newGroup);
  }
}

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает! А как в массиве newGroup заполняются fact и plan, не совсем понимаю... Мы вроде передаем массив, но element это же еще не весь набор данных? или он перезаписывается?

Comment: @VasiliiMaslov на здоровье. `newGroup` - это новая группа, в которой изначально в fact и plan попадают по одному значению из текущего элемента `shops`, да. На следующих же итерациях цикла эта группа может оказаться в `existingGroups`, будучи выбранной по id. И, соответственно, в массивы `plan` и `fact` добавятся новые значения из других элементов `shops`

Comment: @VasiliiMaslov на вашем примере данных: на первой итерации цикла среди существующих групп ничего не находится (что уж там - `groups` вообще пуст), поэтому создаётся новая группа и добавляется в `groups`. На второй итерации в `existingGroups` оказывается группа, созданная на первой итерации, потому что её id совпадает с id второго элемента `shops`. Соответственно, в неё добавляются значения из второго элемента. Третья итерация приводит к созданию новой группы (среди существующих групп нет группы с таким id), а четвёртая - к добавлению значения в группу, созданную на третьей итерации

Answer (score 4):

Для группировки можно воспользоваться методом [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Свернуть предоставленный массив в объект, где ключом будет `id`, и в итоге взять значения, с помощью [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
let shop = [{
  id: 105,
  date: '2018-10-11',
  fact: 100,
  plan: 95
}, {
  id:105,
  date: '2018-10-12',
  fact: 105,
  plan: 100
}, {
  id:106,
  date: '2018-10-11',
  fact: 110,
  plan: 115
}, {
  id:106,
  date: '2018-10-12',
  fact: 120,
  plan: 115
}];
var map = shop.reduce((acc, cur)=>{
acc[cur.id] = acc[cur.id] || { 
  id: cur.id,
  facts: [],
  plans: []
};
acc[cur.id].plans.push(cur.plan);
acc[cur.id].facts.push(cur.fact);
return acc;
},{})

var result = Object.values(map);

console.log(result);
```